# Scss font file not load into Angular project

Tags: html, angular, sass, fonts, angular-json

My font does not download and is not rendered in the DOM.
I've already tested a lot of things, but this damn font isn't loaded.
Thank you in advance for your help !

**fonts.scss** :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat-Medium, sans-serif;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat-SemiBold, sans-serif;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

**styles.scss** (span style is for the test) :

```
@import 'styles/fonts.scss';

span {
  font-family: Montserrat-SemiBold, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

**angular.json** :

```
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/fonts.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },

        "test": {
          "options": {
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/fonts.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
```

**project structure** :

[image: project structure]

**Network console** :

[image: Network console]

**Console** :

[image: Console]

Comment: Why don't u use google fonts? https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat and add it in index.html like <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: It's a workaround, but this method has worked on my other projects, and I'd like it to continue to work like this. Besides, I'm noticing that the images I put in the assets/images folder aren't loading either...

Comment: Double-check your `angular.json` - are you sure src/assets is being included in the assets? You only show the `styles` part of the file.

Comment: for the assets its ok now, I had put this "src/assets/*" to test with my fonts but I had forgotten to put back "src/assets" as before.

Comment: Ok, I took another look and I think your path might be wrong. IIRC relative paths are resolved based on the location of the final compiled css file. And your main entry point `styles.scss` is one level higher in directory tree. Try dropping the `..` part, or alternatively use absolute paths. Or move your `styles.scss` into `styles` directory and update the angular.json to match those changes. I think either should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, neither of them work...